# The role of recursionDepthHolder in log4j2

Tags: log4j2

I am learning the code of log4j2(version:2.13.0) recently.

What is the use of the **recursonDepthHolder** in AbstractLogger.java, and what does it do?

When I debug the other project, I met some problem.

The stack of the exception below:

```java
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursion depth became negative: -2 
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.decrementRecursionDepth(AbstractLogger.java:2174) 
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2154) 
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2135) 
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2011) 
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1983) 
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.error(Log4jLogger.java:319)
```

I am confused about the issue, Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

When logging an event your configuration might use an appender that also performs logging. This is recursive logging since a logging call was made from inside another logging call.

Log4j uses ThreadLocals to optimize performance of some operations. When a recursive call is made Log4j needs to account for this as it can't use the ThreadLocal without corrupting the original logging call.

Note that Log4j also checks for recursive calls inside the AppenderControl. Each Appender is wrapped with its own AppenderControl so if the recursion count is tripped for the Appender on a thread it is likely a recursive call is being made which will result in an endless loop and eventually a StackOverflowError. Instead, Log4j will ignore logging calls once the limit is reached, thus breaking the recursive call cycle.